# Flex mobile project or ActionScript mobile project?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flash-builder, flexbuilder

I'm trying to start develop an Adobe Air app for Android.

I have Adobe Flash Builder 4.5 standard and when I choose new project I see two options:

- Flex mobile project
- ActionScript mobile project

What are the differents between these two options?

Answer (score 1):

In brief, the Flex Mobile uses the Flex framework. You need to decide if this framework will help or hinder your product. It will allow you to use a lot of declarative markup (MXML) and a lot of built in controls and data handling methods. On the other side, it locks you into the "Flex" way of doing things.

Comment: Also an ActionScript mobile project will have better perf than a Flex mobile project

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What do you recommend me?

Comment: If I use ActionScript mobile project, how can I design my UI?

Comment: There are a lot of actionscript frameworks available out there. You really have to evaluate them yourself because you know your project. You can still design a great UI without Flex. You will use fl.controls.* a lot, a build a lot of things yourself. Flex gets you up faster if you don't know actionscript well, but it comes with a lot of overhead. I would highly suggest that you research ActionScript frameworks before you begin your project.